# KSQL WINDOW TUMBLING produce strange key

Tags: sql, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I created a stream starting from this query

```
CREATE TABLE MSG_COUNT_STREAM AS SELECT 1,TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(WINDOWSTART,'yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm','Europe/London') AS START_TS,
  COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM 'source'
  WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 60 SECONDS) GROUP BY 1
  EMIT CHANGES;
```

If I perform a select on the stream I can see all the fields correctly, if instead from confluent I look at the 'key' field of the message, it is formed of strange, unreadable characters. How can I solve?
That's the key
[image]

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: I edited the post, the problem is the key of the table which does not have a readable format after applying the window tubling. Is it possible using only ksqldb to have a window tumbling and a key chosen by me?

Comment: @dune98, I faced the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: @deeplay No sorry, i think that you have to play with key conversion class. At least this strange key is produced by merged data like base_key + window start + window end.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command to check Key Format. But I believe you have already figured it out, it is a combination of keys and window.

```
print MSG_COUNT_STREAM from beginning limit 10;
```